# Solution to a special type of polynomial equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $k$ be any field (maybe need to be algebraically closed), and $n$ be a positive integer, $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring. Then consider the equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n l_i(x)x_i^2=q(x)(x_1+\ldots+ x_n)$$
where $l_i(x)\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $1$, and $q(x)\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$. We want to find the solution $(l_i,q)$ for the equation above. Easy to see 
$$l_i=x_1+\ldots+ x_n$$
$$q=x_1^2+\ldots+ x_n^2$$
is a trivial solution (and any $\mathbb C$ multiple, i.e. $c_i l_i$ for $c_i\in k$). My question is

> is there any other non-trivial solution?

---

In general I am concerned about the solution to
$$\sum_{i=1}^n l_i(x)x_i^2=q(x)(\text{a general linear equation})$$
but let's see the special case first. I have no idea how to do this.

---

**Edit**

Robert's answer shows there are other solutions for $n<5$. Now I want to know the case $n=5$.

Comment: For $n=2$, take $l_i(x)=x_i$ and $q=x_1^2-x_1x_2+x_2^2$ as an example.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for your example. But maybe I should require $n>2$ since this is too special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraically closed is not an issue: this involves solving a linear system of equations for the coefficients of the $l_i$ and $q$, with integer coefficients.

You will find other nontrivial solutions.  For example, for each $i$ you 
could have $l_i = x_1 + \ldots + x_n$, all other $l_j = 0$, $q(x) = x_i^2$.

In the case $n=3$ you could also take 
$l_1(x) = x_2 - x_3$, $l_2(x) = x_1$, $l_3(x) = -x_1$,
$q(x) = x_1 x_2 - x_1 x_3$ (and similarly for permutations of the variables).

In the case $n=4$ you could take
$$ \eqalign{l_{{1}}(x)&=x_{{2}}-x_{{4}}\cr
l_{{2}}(x)&=x_{{1}}-x_{{3}}\cr
l_{{3}}(x)&=-x_{{2}}+x_{{4}}\cr
l_{{4}}(x)&=-x_{{1}}+x_{{3}}\cr
q(x)&=x_{{1}}x_{{2}}-x_{{1}}x_{{4}}-x_{{2}}x_{{3}}+x_{{3}}x_{{4}}\cr}$$
(and again permutations of this).

I suspect this type of solution doesn't exist for $n\ge 5$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in fact I am mostly interested in the case $n=5$. I guess there is no solution for $n=5$, and thought it is a general fact for all $n$ (now you shows it is not). So, is there a way to show no solution for $n=5$?

Comment: And note that the first solution you provided $l_i = x_1 + \ldots + x_n$, all other $l_j = 0$, $q(x) = x_i^2$, should be regarded as an trivial solution (the multiple of $l_i$, coefficients vary for different $i$, sorry for did not make it clear)

Comment: Ok I have proved there is no trivial solution for $n\geq 5$.

Comment: You mean no nontrivial solution?

Comment: Yeah, it is a typo :)  The proof is just by assume a solution and compare coefficients on both sides.